# How to delete random lines from a file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file which contains 10000 lines and I want to delete 5 randomly determined lines from it. How can I do that?

Comment: related: [Python: Choose random line from file, then delete that line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32788380/4279)

Comment: To close-voters: [tag:text-processing] questions are perfectly on topic, this is part of using and administering an Ubuntu system as defined on https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @jfs You’re welcome to add a python answer here as well, even if you just copy it that’s very helpful! Or do you want me to add another copypasta answer? ;)

Answer (score 15):

You can probably solve it more efficiently than with a for-loop that needs to process the whole file once per line to remove.

```bsh
filename="/PATH/TO/FILE"
number=5

line_count="$(wc -l < "$filename")"
line_nums_to_delete="$(shuf -i "1-$line_count" -n "$number")"
sed_script="$(printf '%dd;' $line_nums_to_delete)"

sed -i.bak -e "$sed_script" "$filename"
```

Or in one line (after defining the `filename` and `number` variables or replacing them manually):

```bsh
sed -i.bak -e "$(printf '%dd;' $(shuf -i "1-$(wc -l < "$filename")" -n "$number"))" "$filename"
```

The `-i.bak` switch tells `sed` to edit/replace the input file immediately, but keep a backup copy of the original data, named like the input file but with `.bak` appended to the file name. If you don't want it to make a copy, just write `-i`.

Btw, you don't have to use variables as I did. You can also directly replace `"$number"` and both occurrences of `"$filename"` with the appropriate values. I just did it this way for clarity.

---

To break down and explain the rest of the command:

```bsh
sed -e "SCRIPT" "$filename"
```

runs the text processing tool `sed` on the file specified by the `filename` variable, applying the instructions given as `SCRIPT` argument.

Our `SCRIPT` is dynamically generated in the lines above it, which run commands and assign their outputs to variables. Here we use these commands:

- `wc -l < "$filename"` reads in the file specified by the `filename` variable and outputs the number of lines this file contains.

  - In your case, this should return roughly 10000 according to the size you mentioned in the question.
- `shuf -i "1-$line_count" -n "$number` returns as many unique random numbers as specified by the `number` variable in the range 1 to `$line_count` (both boundaries inclusive).

  - For example, `shuf -i 1-6 -n 2` would emulate throwing two regular six-sided dies.
- `printf '%dd;' ARGUMENTS` returns a formatted string, taking in all `ARGUMENTS` (not quoted this time to treat each random number as a separate argument). The format string `%dd;` will be repeated while there are arguments left, and `%d` will be replaced with the argument represented as a decimal number.

  - Therefore, e.g. an input of `1 7 42` would result in an output of `1d;7d;42d;`.

The resulting `$sed_script` is finally our `SCRIPT` for `sed`. A plain number is treated as address, i.e. the line number on which to apply an action, starting at 1 for the first line of the input file. `d` is the command to delete the specified line, and `;` separates multiple `sed` script commands.

All together, the whole command first examines your input file as specified in the `filename` variable and counts its lines. Then it generates `number` many unique random numbers in the range 1 to the number of lines and constructs a `sed` script out of these to delete each mentioned random line. Finally `sed` runs that script on the file, modifying it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use for loop to get random number and use sed command to delete the line.

```bsh
for i in {0..5};
 do sed -i "$((1 + RANDOM % 10000))d" filename; 
done
```

Comment: `{0..5}` expands to `0 1 2 3 4 5`, so this deletes six lines, you probably mean `{1..5}`. More importantly: What if it tries to delete e.g. line 10000 as the second one, or 9999 as the third… ?

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Shivaditya's answer but without a loop and will delete lines from the whole file not just the first 10 lines:

```bsh
sed -i "$((1+RANDOM%10000))d;$((1+RANDOM%10000))d;$((1+RANDOM%10000))d;$((1+RANDOM%10000))d;$((1+RANDOM%10000))d" filename
```

Will select five random numbers between 1 and 10000 and delete those lines in a single operation.

Comment: What if two or more of these random numbers are the same?

Answer (score 3):

An [answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244445/246819) has this nice `awk` solution for the problem:

```bsh
<file awk -v p=5 -v n=$(<file wc -l) '
  BEGIN {srand()}
  rand() * n-- < p {p--; next}
  {print}'
```

#### Explanation

- `-v p=5` – set variable `p` holding the number of lines to delete
- `-v n=$(<file wc -l)` – set variable `n` holding the line count of the file
- `BEGIN {srand()}` – before processing the file, set the seed for generating random numbers, that’s the prerequisite for using `rand()` to get truly™ random numbers
- `rand() * n-- < p {…}` – A conditional expression running the part in braces if it is true. `rand()` creates a random number between (including) 0 and (excluding) 1, this is multiplied with the line count `n`, which is decreased by 1. If the result is smaller than `p`, the expression is true.
- `p--; next` – decrease `p` by 1 and proceed to the next line ignoring subsequent commands
- `print` – print the currently processed line

The second and last line of the `awk` script are run for every line of the input file, so on every line there’s a chance of `p / n` for the line to be skipped and not printed, while the default action is to just print the line.

#### Example run

I created a file with the letters a–e each in an own line with

```bsh
printf '%s\n' {a..e} >file
```

and set `p=1` to delete one line randomly. I changed the code to also print the values of `n` and `p` for each line before any of them is decreased.

```bsh
$ <file awk -v n=$(<file wc -l) -v p=1 'BEGIN {srand()} {printf "n="n" p="p" "} rand() * n-- < p {p--; print ""; next} {print}'
n=5 p=1
n=4 p=0 b
n=3 p=0 c
n=2 p=0 d
n=1 p=0 e
$ <file awk -v n=$(<file wc -l) -v p=1 'BEGIN {srand()} {printf "n="n" p="p" "} rand() * n-- < p {p--; print ""; next} {print}'
n=5 p=1 a
n=4 p=1 b
n=3 p=1 
n=2 p=0 d
n=1 p=0 e
$ <file awk -v n=$(<file wc -l) -v p=1 'BEGIN {srand()} {printf "n="n" p="p" "} rand() * n-- < p {p--; print ""; next} {print}'
n=5 p=1 a
n=4 p=1 b
n=3 p=1 c
n=2 p=1 d
n=1 p=1
```

#### Further reading

- [The GNU Awk User’s Guide: Chapter 9.1.2 Numeric Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

With gawk, drop the following code into a file (called say, `del_random`)

```awk
function randint(n)
{
    return int(n * rand()) + 1
}

BEGINFILE {
  command = sprintf("wc -l <\"%s\"", FILENAME)
  command | getline total_lines
  srand()
  delete arr
  while (length(arr) < lines_to_del)
  {
    val = randint(total_lines)
    if (val in arr)
       continue
    arr[val] = 1
  }
}
!(FNR in arr)
```

and then execute it as

```
gawk -i inplace -f del_random lines_to_del=5 file1 lines_to_del=20 file2
```

Any number of files can be passed (`file1`, `file2`, ...) and the number of lines to be deleted can be specified on a per-file basis via the `lines_to_del` parameter as show.
The `-i inplace` is the `gawk` equivalent to `sed`'s `-i`

On the other hand if it's the same number of lines need to be deleted from each file you can set `lines_to_del` once as follows:

```
gawk -i inplace -v lines_to_del=5 -f del_random file1 file2
```